# mapView:viewForOverlay: not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a view controller for my Map View.  Inside the viewDidLoad method, I'm setting the mapview's delegate to the controller (self) and then I'm adding the MKOverlay object.  But my mapView:viewForOverlay: method is not getting called, so I still can't get anything to display on my map.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code that adds the overlay object and the viewForOverlay method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are you haven't set up the coordinate or boundingMapRect properties on the MKOverlay correctly. The MapView will only ask for the view if it thinks there is a possibility that it is visible, if its visible rect doesn't intersect the boundMapRect, it won't.

Comment: I added "boundingMapRect = MKMapRectWorld;" to my CustomOverlay init method and the viewForOverlay method got called.